# How to fix misplaced text words in R

Tags: r

I have a data set which the column `title` contains the name of movies. In some of the rows name of movies has been misplaced.

```
[1] "Killer Shrews, The (1959)"       [2] "Kronos (1957)"                         
[3] "Kronos (1973)" [4] "Phantom of the Opera, The (1943)"      
[5] "Runaway (1984)"             [6]  "Slumber Party Massacre, The (1982)"
```

for example, first one should be `The Killer Shrews (1959)`.
I don't know how to fix this problem. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub`.  Capture the characters as a group in the pattern argument and shuffle the backreference in replacement (assuming that the expected output pattern is similar to the one showed for the first element).

```
sub("([^,]+),\\s+([^( ]+)\\s+(.*)", "\\2 \\1 \\3", v1)
#[1] "The Killer Shrews (1959)"          "Kronos (1957)"
#[3] "Kronos (1973)"                     "The Phantom of the Opera (1943)"  
#[5] "Runaway (1984)"                    "The Slumber Party Massacre (1982)"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Killer Shrews, The (1959)", "Kronos (1957)",  "Kronos (1973)", 
 "Phantom of the Opera, The (1943)", "Runaway (1984)", 
 "Slumber Party Massacre, The (1982)" )
```